# Spring MVC handling form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm havings simple form for creating user, but I'm still having following error, I'm struggling with it for a really long time.

```
 Bean property 'user_id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException:

Here is my AdminController methods for managing user's input:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String add(Model model) {
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("users", userService.listUsers());
    return "teams";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@RequestParam("user_id") int user_id, @Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    userService.create(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getFirst_name(),
            user.getLast_name(), user.getRole(), user.getEmail(), user.getStart_date(), user.getId_team());
    return "home";
}
```

My teams.jsp form looks like this:

```
<c:url var="userSaveUrl" value="/teams/userSave" />
<form:form action="${userSaveUrl}" method="post"
  modelAttribute="user" id="user">
   <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="user_id">ID</form:label>
    <form:input path="user_id" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  <form:hidden path="user_id" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="first_name">First name</form:label>                 
                <form:input path="first_name" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="last_name">Last name</form:label>
    <form:input path="last_name" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="email">email</form:label>
    <form:input path="email" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="start_date">Start date</form:label>
    <form:input path="start_date" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="username">Username</form:label>                 
                    <form:input path="username" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="password">Password</form:label>
    <form:input type="password" path="password" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="role">Role</form:label>
    <form:input path="role" class="form-control" />               
    </div>              
    <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="id_team">Team ID</form:label>
    <form:input path="id_team" class="form-control" />
  </div>

   <input name="saveBtn" value="Save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form:form>
```

User.java is following:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int user_id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String first_name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String last_name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)

    private String email;
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date start_date;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String role;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id_team;

    public User() {
        // no-args constructor required by JPA spec
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String first_name, String last_name, String role, String email,
            Date date) {
        // this.id = nextİd.incrementAndGet();
        this.setUsername(username);
        this.setPassword(password);
        this.setFirst_name(first_name);
        this.setLast_name(last_name);
        this.setRole(role);
        this.setEmail(email);
        this.setStart_date(date);

    }

    public User(int id, String username, String password, String first_name, String last_name, String role,
            String email, Date date) {
        // this.id = nextİd.incrementAndGet();
        // this.user_id = id;
        this.setId(id);
        this.setUsername(username);
        this.setPassword(password);
        this.setFirst_name(first_name);
        this.setLast_name(last_name);
        this.setRole(role);
        this.setEmail(email);
        this.setStart_date(date);
    }

    public User(int id, String username, String password, String first_name, String last_name, String role,
            String email, Date date, Integer id_team) {
        // this.id = nextİd.incrementAndGet();
        // this.user_id = id;
        this.setId(id);
        this.setUsername(username);
        this.setPassword(password);
        this.setFirst_name(first_name);
        this.setLast_name(last_name);
        this.setRole(role);
        this.setEmail(email);
        this.setStart_date(date);
        this.setId_team(id_team);
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.user_id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return user_id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        int ID = this.getId();
        String user = "ID: " + Integer.toString(this.getId()) + " Role:" + this.getRole() + "  Username:"
                + this.getUsername() + " Username: " + this.getUsername() + " Email: " + this.getEmail();
        return user;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getStart_date() {
        return start_date;
    }

    public void setStart_date(Date start_date) {
        this.start_date = start_date;
    }

    public Integer getId_team() {
        return id_team;
    }

    public void setId_team(Integer id_team) {
        this.id_team = id_team;
    }
}
```

And finally UserJDBCTemplate.java method for creating an entitny in DB:

```
@Override
public void create(int id, String username, String password, String first_name, String last_name, String role,
    String email, Date date, int id_team) {
    String SQL = "insert into Users (id_user, username, password,first_name,last_name,role,email,date,id_team) values (?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id, username, password, first_name, last_name, role, email, date, id_team);
}
```

I've tried everything, but I can't get to a problem.

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the setter and the getter to `setUser_id` and `getUser_id`, to match the name of the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please auto generate your getters and setters through ide, 
  for example I do see that, 
  At User class the getter method is

```
public int getId() {
      return user_id;
  }
```

This will be,

```
public int getUser_id() {
      return user_id;
  }
```

Comment: Almost 3 minutes before you posted this, Lenusska commented that this makes no difference.

Comment: In my previous comment, I just refactored it, I didn't generate it. But after generating, it's working.

Comment: Cool!! Please you your ide every time that makes simpler to code